# How to Reset my input tags in react.js using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code I have so far it outputs but I put in the names however I want to create a reset buttons that clears the state back to a empty state

```
import { useState } from "react";

function resetName() {
  this.firstName.value = "";
  this.lastName.value = "";
}
export default function Test() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  const fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`;

  return (
    <div>
      First Name:
      <input
        value={firstName}
        onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      Last Name:{" "}
      <input
        value={lastName}
        onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      {fullName}
      <br />
      <button value={resetName}>Reset!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Answer (score 3):

Call `setFirstName` and `setLastName` to reset the input values.

```js
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
function resetName() {
    setFirstName("");
    setLastName("");
}
```

And set the `onClick` attribute of the `<button>`:

```html
<button onClick={resetName}>Reset!</button>
```